# How to create a custom template for custom taxonomy wp-tag-cloud?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, archive-template, cloud

I created a custom taxonomy for "Course Topics." Using the `wp_tag_cloud` I am able to create a custom cloud for this custom taxonomy. When you click on one of the terms in the cloud, it takes you to a filtered page. I am stuck trying to figure out how to create a custom template for the archive/filter for the taxonomy "Course Topic."

I did find that it uses the `archive.php` template, but I would like it to be separate from the default.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new template named e.g. `taxonomy-course_topic.php`

In my example `course_topic` is the name of the custom taxonomy you registered. First parameter of `register_taxonomy()` function.

See:

- [`register_taxonomy`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)
- [Taxonomy template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display)